# Symfony 3.3.8 ignoring custom normalizer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

why symfony ignoring my custom normalizer?

**src/AppBundle/Serializer/Normalizer/ExceptionNormalizer.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

/**
 * Class ExceptionNormalizer
 */
class ExceptionNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array()): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof \Exception;
    }
}
```

**src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    ...
    app.normalizer.exception:
        class: AppBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\ExceptionNormalizer
        tags:
            - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

**app/config/config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    #- { resource: services.yml } exclude default services file
    - { resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Exception output

> {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","exception":[{"message":"AppBundle\Entity\User object not found.","class":"Symfony\Component.....

Expected exception output

> {}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take some time to read the posting guidelines or it is likely you will get negative votes.

Comment: Looks like it has nothing to do with the normalizer - there's no User entity it's trying to work with

Comment: @JasonRoman its exception normalizer, not user's normalizer. I try to redifine exception output on something else, but i've got same string with exception info

Comment: Show the code where you define and call Serializer or this Normalizer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be normalizing exception. Instead, create listener for this kind of Exception, process it(for example, write to log) and return desired output as Response.

```
class ExceptionListener
{
/** @var LoggerInterface */
private $logger;


public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $e = $event->getException();
    if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse(['error' => $e->getViolations()], 422)
    } elseif ($e instanceof DomainException) {
        $this->logger->warning('Exception ' . get_class($e) , ['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        $event->setResponse(
        new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Something is wrong with your request.'], 400);
    } elseif ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Not found.'], 404);
    } else {
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse(['error' => $this->translator->trans('http.internal_server_error')], 500);
    }
}
```

}

Update services.yml

```
  app.exception_listener:
    class: Application\Listeners\ExceptionListener
    arguments: ['@domain.logger']
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Further reading about listeners and events https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Your normalizer is most likely ignored because you did not register it in your serializer.